# Improve Wordpress statistic in frontend using "Google Analytics Dashboard for WP"

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

My question is for the plugin [Google Analytics Dashboard for WP powered by Alin Marcu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/). I tried to ask directly to the author, unfortunately without success.

This plugin allow me in backend to see all statistic for all posts by adding a icon in "All post" list. Please see these images as example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWbMd.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UMXr.png

This plugin fetch data from my Google Analytics. How can I do to move this icon in frontend? I want to move this icon under a post.

This is the code of the button in backend.

```
<td class="gadwp_stats column-gadwp_stats"><a id="gadwp-9338" title="MOVIE" href="#9338" class="gadwp-icon dashicons-before dashicons-chart-area"></a></td>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Or, if have sense or is possible, can I move the content of the page edit.php?post_type=post on frontend?

Answer (score 1):

The feature your asking for will be available in GADWP v4.8, [more details on GitHub](https://github.com/deconf/Google-Analytics-Dashboard-for-WP).